# How to map an ftp share folder to a local drive using C#?

Tags: c#, ftp

How do I map an ftp share folder to a local drive using C#?  Is there any class library available for this?

I need to achieve the same functionality as NetDrive(http://www.netdrive.net/) offers using FTP ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can leverage someone else's work and get a headstart. The makers of NetDrive for instance offer [an SDK](http://www.netdrive.net/features.html) - not sure what that requires / costs, however. But it might be worth an inquiry, no?

And maybe, if you combine [this approach](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/ftp/how-can-i-map-to-an-ftp-server-as-a-drive-.aspx) to define a remote FTP site as a Windows network share, and then use [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mapnetdrive.aspx) in C# to mount a network share as a drive, you might get your job done :-)

Comment: But internally it uses SMB protocol not FTP

Comment: You're saying you want to map the "share folder", do you want to map it through FTP or through normal sharing services? You need to be more clear in your questions, there's a reason you're not getting any good answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very tall order - if you actually want a local drive, e.g. X:\, to access an FTP site, you'd surely need to write a driver.  *Not an easy task*.

If you want it to simply appear in Windows Explorer somewhere - you can use the shell extension as Marco's answer suggests.  But don't expect to be able to treat it like a regular drive.

Answer (score 0):

To create a virtual drive or a folder on existing drive and expose remote FTP server contents that way you need a filesystem driver. Or use can use our Callback File System (CBFS) product which lets you write the code in user-mode and includes a pre-created filesystem driver. CBFS includes a sample, SFTPDisk, that does exactly what you need, but with SFTP protocol (SFTP is not FTP but SSH File Transfer Protocol).

Note, that in FTP there's no function to upload a block to the middle of the existing file. This makes some file write operations trickier than with SFTP or local filesystem - you may need to cache the whole file and upload it asynchronously when it's closed by the client.

Answer (score 0):

There's a project in C# to use an FTP folder as virtual drive -> http://amalgam.codeplex.com/ (it uses dokan).

There's a freeware program that does the same thing -> http://www.ferrobackup.com/ftpuse/