# how to Create Virtual drive in local machine from FTP folder in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to map an ftp share folder to a local drive using C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402512/how-to-map-an-ftp-share-folder-to-a-local-drive-using-c)

Hi,

how to Create Virtual drive in local machine from  FTP folder in C# ?
Any code snippet...

Can anyone please tell me how to create some virtual drive in my system using c#.net.
My aim is to get files and directoreies from my ftp host and show in the local system under some virtual drive. so that user can access the contents as normal system contents. can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: How "drive-y" does it have to be? Can't you just map it up as a network drive?

Comment: @Lasse: I didn't get you ? I want to do using C#

Comment: What I mean is: Does it have to look like a full drive, or can it be a network mapped drive? I understand you want to do it using C#, but you're not very clear *what* you want done. Can you tell us which manual function you want to do using C#? Is it the same as going into explorer and just adding a network drive against a share?

Comment: Yes..Network map drive or fill drive anything is OK.

Comment: Network drive is not the same as "FTP host". Do you want to map up a normal FTP Server as a drive in Windows, or do you want to map up a normal network share as a drive in Windows? Your questions will be closed again and again since you can't tell us what you want done.

Comment: @Lasse : I want to map normal network share as a drive in Windows

Answer (score 2):

the command to make a virtual drive from a share folder is

```
net use \\some\share <drive> /u:<username to access the folder> <password for the user>
```

e.g.

```
net use \\some\share j: /u:domain\user password
```

in c# you can do this through Process class

```
Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"use \\some\share j: /u:domain\user password";
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            proc.Start();

            proc.WaitForExit();
            int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

Comment: I have edited my question can you have a look ?

Answer (score 1):

As ajay_whiz points out, you can shell out to the command line and call "net use". If you need to do it directly from C# without launching a separate process, you'd have to P/Invoke. This isn't straightforward, but it's doable - here's a nice [blog post](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MapDriveLetter.aspx) by BlackWasp explaining how.

As the blog post explains, you can define this external function:

```
[DllImport("mpr.dll")]
static extern UInt32 WNetAddConnection3(IntPtr hWndOwner, ref NETRESOURCE
lpNetResource, string lpPassword, string lpUserName, uint dwFlags);
```

This structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NETRESOURCE
{
    public uint dwScope;
    public uint dwType;
    public uint dwDisplayType;
    public uint dwUsage;
    public string lpLocalName;
    public string lpRemoteName;
    public string lpComment;
    public string lpProvider;
}
```

and this constant:

```
const uint RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 1;
```

Then call the API like this:

```
var networkResource = new NETRESOURCE() {
  dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK, 
  pLocalName = "Z:", 
  lpRemoteName = @"\\server\share", 
  lpProvider = null 
};

uint result = WNetAddConnection3(this.Handle, ref networkResource, null, null, 0);

if ( result != 0 )
    throw new Exception("drive mapping failed with error code " + result);
```

Here is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385418(VS.85).aspx) for WNetAddConnection3.

Comment: Looking at your edited question, my answer here is not going to do what you want - it's for Windows file sharing only. I don't know of a way to make an FTP folder look like it's local.

Answer (score 0):

Following links can help.

[Link 1](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/map-ftp-server-as-drive_t7292.html)

[MSDN Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/b3952b56-e79d-42a3-8b5e-cf844e61b551)

the trick is you need to add the IP of your FTP in LMHOSTS file present in your system and then you can use it as the way i explained in my 1st answer