# How to connect to FTP Server using SSH FTP or SFTP in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to map an ftp share folder to a local drive using C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402512/how-to-map-an-ftp-share-folder-to-a-local-drive-using-c)
>   [Anybody has Client library on SFTP in C# ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308900/anybody-has-client-library-on-sftp-in-c)

hi,

How to connect to FTP Server using SSH FTP or SFTP in C# ?
Any code snippet.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402512/how-to-map-an-ftp-share-folder-to-a-local-drive-using-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404710/how-to-mount-a-sftp-share-as-a-network-drive-programmatically-in-c, and your other earlier questions.  You said you'd avoid re-asking questions, Swapnil.  What happened?

Comment: @michael : It is completely diffrent question i guess,previously i was asking questions related to FTP, now it is SFTP connection i am asking.How to connect only i want to know..

Comment: This looks different..,  It's no longer asking about mapping a drive, just accessing an SFTP folder, and SFTP does pose a challenge for the .NET developer...

Comment: Swapnil: are you forgetting [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404710/how-to-mount-a-sftp-share-as-a-network-drive-programmatically-in-c)?  Is that substantially different?

Comment: Michael :Mounting is diffrent and connecting to FTP server through SFTP is diffrent i guess?

Comment: Goodness, here's [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308900/anybody-has-client-library-on-sftp-in-c).  Swapnil, you need to step back and put the pieces together.  You're not going to learn anything by asking the same question different ways.

Comment: michael :oops sorry this article is same as above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not a lot of options that I'm aware of, unless things have changed in the last year.  We ended up just using a third party (non .NET) app that was scriptable: http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

We created a script, and called it from within our .NET app using the System.Diagnostic.Process class.

However, Rebex DOES have a .Net component for this if you're willing to pay for it.  There's also a good explanation of the difference between FTP, FTPS, and SFTP.

http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/