# Apache Mina FTP Server SFTP configuration and connecting SFTP connection using FileZiza or WInscp or any ftp client took over secure channel

Tags: apache, ssl, sftp, keytool, client-certificates

I have downloaded and coinfigred Apache Mina base FTP Server from [here](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/).
I am able to connect using FTP with.

When i am trying to configured SFTP with below configuration I am getting error when i trying with SFTP connection using FIleZila or any other client.

Server Configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
    id="myServer">

    <listeners>
        <nio-listener name="default" port="2222" implicit-ssl="true"  idle-timeout="60">
            <ssl>
                <keystore file="mykeystore.jks" password="ftpkey"  key-password="ftpkey" />
            </ssl>
        </nio-listener>
    </listeners> 

    <!--<file-user-manager file="users.properties"
        encrypt-passwords="true" />-->
```

below are the Command i am using to generate the certificate :

```
keytool -genkey -alias ftpkeya -keysize 1024 -dname "cn=mydomain.com,o=mycompany,ou=company,l=Capelle,s=NL,c=NL" -keystore mykeystore.jks -keypass ftpkey -storepass ftpkey -keyalg RSA 



keytool -list -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass ftpkey  -v

keytool -export -alias ftpkeya -keystore mykeystore.jks -storepass ftpkey -file serverCertificate.arm -rfc
```

I am using keytool to generate keysore and certificate. When i generated certificate and configured in above server configuration my server is started with SFTP support but when I am trying to connect with using FTP client connection is refused,

I am getting different exception in my server logs with different FTP client :

**Bellow server exception logs for while I am using WinScp.**

```
[ WARN] 2017-05-08 09:49:16,018 [] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] EXCEPTION :
org.apache.mina.core.write.WriteToClosedSessionException
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.clearWriteRequestQueue(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:641)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.removeNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:592)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.removeSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:562)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$800(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1149)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[ WARN] 2017-05-08 09:49:16,019 [] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] Client closed connection before all replies could be sent, last reply was WriteRequest: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=20 cap=20: 35 33 30 20 41 63 63 65 73 73 20 64 65 6E 69 65...]
[ INFO] 2017-05-08 09:49:16,019 [] [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] CLOSED
```

**And different more when I am using filezila.**

**Client Side Logs :**

```
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 172.27.136.44:2222...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    open "admin@172.27.136.44" 2222
Error:  Network error: Connection refused
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

**Server Side Logs while connecting from FileZilla**

```
 [ WARN] 2017-05-08 09:42:45,913 [] [172.27.136.44] EXCEPTION :
        java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:280)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:44)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:695)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:668)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:657)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1141)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[ERROR] 2017-05-08 09:42:45,916 [] [172.27.136.44] Exception caught, closing session
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:280)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:44)
```

I am expecting there should not be any difference in server logs while connecting from any FTP client I am not understanding why and what is the problem here. I have refer this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411817/how-to-connect-to-ftp-server-using-ssh-ftp-or-sftp-in-c)

Thanks in advance for any kind of help and information.

Comment: Show us client side logs too.

Comment: Client side filezilla logs has added. I am not sure where I can get winscp logs can obtain.

Comment: The log just confirms my answer. - You are connecting with SFTP protocol to FTP(S) server. That cannot work. Use FTP(S) on client-side - Or if you actually need to implement SFTP server, then you are on a completely wrong track.

Comment: SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol/Secure File Transfer Protocol) was designed as an extension of SSH to provide file transfer capability, so it usually uses only the SSH port for both data and control.

Comment: So If i want custom port I should go for FTPS configuration am i correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously confused with FTP/FTPS/SSL/SFTP stuff.

- FTP with SSL/TLS is FTPS, not SFTP. SFTP is a completely different and incompatible protocol; and it does not use TLS/SSL.
- Your default port 2222 is confusing. It's seemingly based on SSH/SFTP default port 22. While FTP uses port 21. And for implicit TLS/SSL (`implicit-ssl="true"`), it actually uses port 990. Though there's no reason to use implicit TLS/SSL.

Chances are that you are trying to connect with SFTP protocol to your FTP(S) server.

Comment: We need specific port not the default port 22 so I kpet 2222 for testing purpose. That same port we are planning to open fire wall once we things are ready and ready to go live.

Comment: So If i want custom port I should go for FTPS configuration am i correct ? 

i refer in this link:

https://www.howtogeek.com/194740/what-is-the-difference-between-ftps-and-sftp/

Comment: I need to have FTPS (also known as FTP Secure and FTP-SSL)  only the SFTP i read the link shared by you and other links as well. 

I think i can configure FTPS server and exchange certificate between client and server Is what my need. I created little mess by mixing FTPS and SFTS ..

Comment: Thanks, I will add my configuration changes for server aand steps to connect this server from client.

Comment: What does it mean *"I need to have FTPS only the SFTP"*? So what do you want? FTPS or SFTP?

Comment: You have quoted SFTP definition in [your comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843286/apache-mina-ftp-server-sftp-configuration-and-connecting-sftp-connection-using-f#comment74724322_43843286).

Comment: FTP with SSL/TLS is FTPS is what i mean